# ListView with background image

Tags: android, image, listview

I would like to have an image as background of listview.
No one per item, but for all, and that do not move as listview moves.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/the_background_image"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tryed giving the top element a background but it just didn't work properly. This did the charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used this:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/lists_header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="2dip"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/shopper_background"
    android:background="@drawable/paper_frame" />
```

Where paper_frame is a 9.patch drawable.

That provides a (stretched to fill the ListView area) fixed background image that doesn't scroll with the list, and might be what you are trying to do.

I want the image to stretch to be the height of the list (i.e. the top and/or bottom can be off the screen if the list is long) and am looking for how to do that.