# Android ArrayAdapter Background Image

Tags: android, background-image, android-arrayadapter

I want to set a background image to my listview so that regardless of where you are in the list, you see the same background image.

For scrollview, this is just a case of setting the background image of the scrollview in the XML attributes, but doing likewise for the listview doesn't work

I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter as such:

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TableRow>{

    private ArrayList<TableRow> items;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<TableRow> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_season, null);
            }
            TableRow o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                v = o;
            }

            return v;
    }


}
```

and then

```
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
lv.setId(R.id.list_listView1);

ArrayList<TableRow> tablerows = new ArrayList<TableRow>();    

// create some TableRow's and add them to tablerows

CustomAdapter vAdapt = new CustomAdapter(this, R.id.list_season_item_name,tablerows);

lv.setAdapter(vAdapt);

setContentView(lv);
```

and my xml:

```
<ListView 
android:id="@+id/list_listView1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/standard_layout">
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/list_linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/standard_layout">
    <TextView 
        android:text="list_textview1" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"          
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:id="@+id/list_season_row" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"  
            android:id="@+id/list_season_item_name" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/standard_item">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:id="@+id/list_season_item_season" 
            android:gravity="left" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/standard_season">
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
```

and my styles

```
<style name="standard_item" parent="@style/standard_font">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
<style name="standard_season" parent="@style/standard_font">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="standard_layout" parent="@style/standard_font">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_img</item>
</style>
```

Setting a style for each TableRow just makes each one use the whole background image, which is not what I'm after.

Also there is probably a better way to implement my ArrayAdapter but I'm not keen on changing it unless there is no other way to get the effect I'm after

This has been bugging me for a while, so any help would be appreciated,

Thanks
Spoon Thumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the default ListView cache color hint optimization by making it transparent:

```
<style name="standard_layout" parent="@style/standard_font">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_img</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Comment: Yeah, I read that blog and tried your suggestion, but my lists still come out black. The books on the wooden background example has the entire image repeated for each item in the list, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm basically after this: http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/2980/scrollviewbackground.png but for a listview (this is done with a scrollview)

Comment: Ok, I part-solved the problem this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137898/listview-with-background-image . Only thing is the background colour changes when scrolling, so I guess it is just cachColorHint is not working for some reason